# What is the maximum kinetic energy of the electron after the collision during comton scattering?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, electrons, collision

A 10 keV X-ray scatters off a stationary electron. What is the maximum kinetic energy of the electron after the collision? Im not sure where to begin with this. I know the Compton scattering formula but I am not sure if I need to use it here or how to use it. Thanks for nay help.

Comment: Knowing a formula is different from knowing the physics of the situation. Let challenge you to understand the physics by thinking about how the incoming kinetic energy and momentum could be shared between the particles after the collision depending on the angle. You should take a lot of time to think about situations, then see if a formula "says" the same thing.  That type of thinking is missing in most introductory physics classes, (and all other subjects, IMHO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the maximum kinetic energy of the electron will come if the photon strikes the electron head on and in the compton equation the angle will be 180degrees, if we know the wavelengths of the photon before and after we can calculate the change in energy of the photon, this change in energy will go into the electron's kinetic energy. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes this helps thanks.